# Can i Mix $_get and $_post?

Tags: php, post, get

in order to edit my entries i want to:

```
    <form id="pregunta" name="pregunta" class="form_pregunta" method="post" action="pregunta.php?id=26">
<h2>Titulo de la pregunta</h2><input name="q" id="q" class="q" value="este es mi títiulo " type="text">
<h2>Describe tu pregunta</h2>
<textarea name="texto" id="texto" style="width: 98%;">&lt;p&gt;esta es mi descripcion&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
<h2>Etiquetas</h2>
<input name="tags" id="tags" onmouseover="mostrar_tooltip('nube_e','','0','70','')" onmouseout="ocultar_tooltip('nube_e')" value="dos,tres,una,">
<input name="responde_a" style="display: none;" id="responde_a" value="0">
<button name="pregunta" id="pregunta" type="submit">form_edit_question_button</button>
</form>
```

And then in file.php

i'd like to `$_get['id']` and `$_post['inputs']`

**but when i go:**

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_pregunta'])){
     echo 'lalalalalalalalalalalalalalala';
     post_edit_pregunta();
 }
```

it won't ever enter :S. is that normal or i'm missing something... i wanted not to have a hidden input with the id of the post i want to edit..

Comment: which value do you wanna have in your $_POST['edit_pregunta']? Is there any reason why it should be set? I think a form does not have a value...

Comment: 2 things you'll see in the answers below that are both correct.  You have to have an <input> (or select etc..) in your form for any values to be posted, and your id isn't currently being displayed using php, so it won't be including in your action.  Fix both, and voila! :)

Comment: updated with the complete form code :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why avoid hidden form elements? I've always found they work best for things like this, obtain the ID simply with `$_POST['id']` or something along those lines. Also, here's a good way to see if a POST field is present - `if (array_key_exists('edit_pregunta', $_POST)) { .. }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but forms don't send their `name` when submitted, much less their `id`.

You could do the following instead:

```
<form id="edit_pregunta" method="post" action="file.php?id='$this->id'">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_pregunta" value="anything">
    ... //inputs here
</form>
```

and your `if` should now enter.

Comment: The way your form is made, just by adding the hidden field I pointed out your problem should be solved. Seeing that your submit button has a name of "pregunta", you could check for `$_POST['pregunta']` instead.

Comment: why if i ask if(!isset($_post['q']))
          echo 'no!<br>'; it allways says no?

Comment: Are you sure you're asking for `$_POST` (capital letters)? Try printing the entire `$_POST` array using `print_r($_POST)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're checking for your form's "id" attribute. This is not sent when the form is submitted, only values in `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` are sent.

You should check for one of those.

**Edit:** Your button name is "pregunta", so that is the POST variable you should be checking for, eg

```
if(isset($_POST['pregunta'])){
```

---

Just to comment in general on mixing params in the form's "action" and inputs, you can mix them as long as the form method is "post". You cannot set GET params in the form's action and use the "get" method

```
<!-- Good -->
<form action="proc.php?id=123" method="post">
<input name="foo" value="foo">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<!-- Bad -->
<form action="proc.php?id=123" method="get">
<input name="foo" value="foo">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: If you look at his code his trying to post to `somepage.php?id=...`, I think that's the id he want to get.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem at all with having get and post variables in the same request, but are you sure your syntax is correct? If this is normal php, shouldn't you write

```
<form id="edit_pregunta" method="post" action="file.php?id=<?php echo $this->id; ?>">
        ... //inputs here
</form>
```

#### [Edit]

The problem is (if I'm correct and this is standard php) that you generate a form that looks something like this:

```
<form id="edit_pregunta" method="post" action="file.php?id='$this->id'">
        ... //inputs here
</form>
```

This will make id look like this: `'$this->id'` (including the '-signs). When what you want is something like this:

```
<form id="edit_pregunta" method="post" action="file.php?id=51">
        ... //inputs here
</form>
```

Then `$_GET['id']` would be `51`.

#### [Edit2]

Also, I think you need to change

```
if(isset($_POST['edit_pregunta'])){
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['pregunta'])){
```

If I'm not mistaken the name of a form doesn't get sent to the server, however, the name of the submit-button does, but I might be wrong about that part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, I've done it several times.
Probably something else is wrong with your code.

Is there any control with name="edit_pregunta" or is it just the id of the form? IDs are not sent to the server.

Comment: also button, i'll edit my question with my real form. i was focused on my $_get and $_post stuff

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the `id` to the form will not create the `$_POST['edit_pregunta']` you verify.

Instead, inside the form tag, add an `<input name="foo" />`; in the php script verify `$_POST['foo']`

Answer (score 0):

While the HTTP spec doesn't disallow query parameters in POST methods, it is somewhat unusual. You'd be better off using a hidden input field in the form to pass any non-user values up to the script.

That said, the syntax for your form is wrong. You need to use "echo" to insert the value of $this->id into the action.

Answer (score 0):

Use input type="submit" in place of button tag.
You need name for form submission and activate php script!

HTML Code:

```
<form action="change.php" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="p1" class="change_text" placeholder="New Password"/></br>
    <input type="password" name="p2" class="change_text" placeholder="Re-Password"/></br>
    <input type="submit" name="change" value="Change Password" id="change" />
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['change']) {
        $p1=$_POST['p1'];
    }
?>
```